# How to set word wrap for JComboBox?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to display multiple-line text for each item in combobox. Words should go to the next line automatically if the exceed the width of combobox. How to achieve this?

```
String meanings;// array which contains pretty long sentences
JComboBox<String> meaningsComboBox=new JComboBox<String>(meanings);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe wrapping each value into html will help you(this trick work with JLabels), example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html).
In another way, I think, you need make custom renderrer, example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#renderer)